# Unknown timegap in django + uwsgi profile

Tags: django, nginx, profiling, uwsgi

I'm trying to understand why my website (django + uwsgi + nginx) response is take about 1.5 seconds. 
I'm using  jazzband/django-silk for this purpose, and in it's admin panel I see that request takes about 800ms

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJNaZ.png

But when I inspect nginx / uwsi logs I see that execution time is much more from 1.5 to 2 seconds

uwsgi log:

```
=> generated 99087 bytes in 1818 msecs (HTTP/2.0 200) 4 headers in 133 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

nginx log (time in the end)

```
10.136.52.100 - - [27/May/2020:14:51:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 12250 "https://localhost:4443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.100 Safari/537.36" 1.819 1.820 .
```

So I'm losing about 500ms on every request. Can somebody help me to understand what is wrong, or this is right behavior ?

Config of uwsgi bellow:

```
[uwsgi]
module                  = newsletter.wsgi
master                  = true
processes               = 10
socket                  = /var/run/newsletter/app.sock
chmod-socket            = 777
vacuum                  = true
enable-threads          = true
ignore-sigpipe          = true
ignore-write-errors     = true
disable-write-exception = true
```

Comment: Just curious if you've tried this _without_ silk? I've found it really slows down response times. Otherwise, I would check your database queries and network traffic (between the server and client, but also between the server and the database, if on different hosts.

Comment: Without silk time is same. 
It can not be sql queries or network traffic between server and database because as you can see on screenshot of silk profile we have overall time of script execution (with database processing included) and it is 895 ms.
Concerning network traffic between server and client - in my calculations I use uwsgi logs, not browser network logs for measure final time, and it is time, as I understand, for script execution, not for sending to client.

Comment: This is how looks browser network time log: https://imgur.com/a/BLWOIx3

Comment: Have you checked the network between you and the server, and between the server and the database, etc.? I've found that often these get lost somewhere. E.g. looking at SQL query times doesn't include the network, or putting the objects into memory in Python, etc. It'd also be useful to run a "real" profiler on your code to make sure it's not something there - py-spy works well with django.